# minipages in fbox horizontal misalignment when figure is included (not float)

Tags: floats, minipage

I am trying to place some text and a figure next to each other and trying to avoid wrapfigure at the same time :-)

Placing two minipages inside a framedbox works just fine: the text can be aligned by the [t]op

However, if I place a figure in one minipage instead of text I get misalignment.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Title Page
\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section*{Alignment problems}

\noindent\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}
 A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\textwidth}
 B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B
\end{minipage}
}

\vspace{2cm}

\noindent\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}
 A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\textwidth}
 \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{gull}
\end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

This results in something like this
[image: Output from the TeX code above]

Comment: Don't forget `%` after `\fbox{` and after the last `\end{minipage}` in the fbox. Unless you really want more space at either side.

Answer (score 2):

The result is what's expected. Probably not what *you* expected, though.

When you do `\parbox[t]` or `\begin{minipage}[t]`, the box's reference point is the same as the first item's in it. The reference point always sits on the baseline, the imaginary line where usually letters are placed on.

The reference point of the first item in the box containing the gull image is the bottom of the image, in the text box it's the first line made of A's (because a paragraph is split into line wide boxes).

So you have to make TeX think that the gull image's reference point is higher. The `adjustbox` package comes to rescue: its `valign` key allows placing the reference point as if a just line of text is above the baseline and the rest is below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

% Title Page
\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section*{Alignment problems}

\noindent\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}
 A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A
 A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\textwidth}
 B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B
\end{minipage}
}

\vspace{2cm}

\noindent\fbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}
 A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A
 A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\textwidth}
 \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth,valign=t]{../duck}
\end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Not having a gull, I opted for a duck, which is the favorite animal in this site.

Alternatively, add an invisible item to both boxes:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}
 \vspace{0pt}
 A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A
 A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A A
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\textwidth}
 \vspace{0pt}
 \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{../duck}
\end{minipage}
```

The result will be alike: the first item in both minipages is the vertical space.

Comment: Thank you very much for that very instructive and very useful reply. The second solution is elegant, albeit 'dirty' -- I'll stick with that. Again thx.

Answer (score 0):

Before `\includegraphics`  apply `\vspace{-\baselineskip}`.
This will move the the bottom of the image down by `\baselineskip`.

Comment: This answer is a little bit short -- could you elaborate on this a little bit

Comment: (a) it will the baseline _up_ not down (b) this much more ad hoc than egreg's answer

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! An answer should (at best) contain a full compilable example. Such short things would fit better in comments below the question.